# How to include wildcard match in the replace portion of a find / replace operation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using the Find and Replace dialog in Visual Studio 2010. I don't have a problem getting results to match the find criteria. The problem is, the result after the find / replace operation concludes is an * in the string. Visual Studio is treating the asterisk as a literal character and places * in the result. Not what I need and not all that useful.

I'm using this for the Find criteria:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(*)
```

I'm using this for the Replace criteria:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(*, new { @class = "className" })
```

If this is my starting string,

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( x => x.price)
```

I want the result to be

```
@Html.TextBoxFor( x => x.price, new { @class = "className" })
```

not this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(*, new { @class = "className" })
```

How do I perform a find with a wildcard (*) but not replace the match with a literal * ?

Comment: Use regular expressions. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select "use Regular Expressions".

Find `\@Html\.TextBoxFor\({.*}\)`

Replace with `@Html.TextBoxFor(\1, new { @class = "className" })`